# Yammer Token in SharePoint Online

Tags: yammer, sharepoint-online

I am fetching the data from Yammer Using Rest api.
I am passing Bearer +"Yammer app developer Token" in the header.
Is it required to pass the token in SharePoint online since Both Yammer and SharePoint are in Office 365 Tenant.

If required how can i pass the token dynamically in the header instead of hard coding the token.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the process of getting user specific yammer access token, once you got the access token that will be valid for years. here is the process you can follow https://developer.yammer.com/docs/authentication-1[click here](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/authentication-1)